# How to address ChatGPT's LLM limitation of providing only topmost records for tabular data queries in PDF documents within my RAG application?

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, chatgpt-api

I am trying to develop a rag application using LangChain and ChatGPT's language model (LLM) where users can query PDF documents for information. However, I'm encountering an issue when users query specific records within tabular structures in the PDF documents. The responses provided by ChatGPT's LLM seem to only reflect the topmost record. For eg. There are some tables which have more that 100 rows, if asked about full table, llm is giving only top 20 rows.

I'm looking for suggestions or techniques to enhance the response generation process and improve the relevance and accuracy of responses, particularly when dealing with tabular data in PDF documents. Here is the code.

```
class PdfQA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.open_api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
    
    def get_files_from_dir(self, dir):
        files = [os.path.join(dir, f) for f in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, f))]

        return files

    def load_docs(self, file_path):
        loader = TextLoader(file_path, encoding='utf8')
        docs = loader.load()
        return docs
    
    def create_chain(self, chunked_dir):
        
        files = self.get_files_from_dir(chunked_dir)
        
        list_of_all_docs=[]
        for file in files:
            document = self.load_docs(file)
            list_of_all_docs.append(document[0])
        
       

        texts = [doc.page_content for doc in list_of_all_docs]
        text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
            chunk_size = 6200,
            chunk_overlap  = 400,
            length_function = len
        )
        
        chunks = text_splitter.create_documents(texts)
        
        
        embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
        
        # Create vector database
        db = Chroma.from_documents(chunks, embeddings)


        chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.3), 
                                                        retriever=
                                                        db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 3}),
                                                        return_source_documents=True)
        return chain
    
    def get_response_from_query(self, query, chat_history, chunked_dir):
        chain = self.create_chain(chunked_dir)
        
        #answer = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)
        result = chain({"question": query, "chat_history":chat_history}, return_only_outputs=True)
        result['question']= query
        result['chat_history']= chat_history
        return result
```

I have tried experimenting with hyper parameters, but couldn't improve llm's response. Can you please suggest me an approach that I should take to make llm's response better.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the number of Tokens returned by ChatGPT is limited and it strictly depends on the used model and the sum of prompt and completion tokens. If the PDF is quite large ChatGPT will try to truncate the response in order to fit the answer in the tokens allowed window. If you are sure that you do not exceed the tokens limit, try to enter a more specific Instructions parameter asking the assistant to add all the details. What you cand do is just engineering the Instructions to force the LLM to return the complete results, but unfortunately there is no silver bullet to make it reply all the times with your desired output; there is always a certain degree of freedom in its answers and in some cases you need to instruct it to return more details after the first answer. I have used ChatGPT's new Assistant APIs for a similar purpose with small PDF documents and especially with tabular data it sometimes tend to reduce the set and return only part of it. There is little you can do to fix it 100%. Instructions engineering can only help you mitigate the problem but not solve it completely. I hope they'll fix that in the near future.